# More than one round in my Spot the Difference game (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a Spot the Difference game and I got it working but it works in the following way, you got two images and when you click on the 5 differences a message appears saying that you won and asking you if you want to play the next round.

My question is... how can I "restart" the thing with two different images and different differences as a next level?? I want everything to happen in the same page, I don't want to go to a different html page to show the second level...

This is my actual code :)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoYRZq

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // When clicked, show difference
      $('#transparentmap AREA').click(function() {
      var theDifference = '#'+$(this).attr('id')+'-diff';
      $(theDifference).css('display', 'inline');
        $(theDifference).data('clicked', true);

      // When all differences selected/clicked, show email submission form
      if($('#camera-diff').data('clicked') && $('#down-diff').data('clicked') && $('#eye-diff').data('clicked') && $('#flour-diff').data('clicked') && $('#uni-diff').data('clicked')) {
        $('#form_container').css('display', 'inline');
      }

      });
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hard to test this since the codepen is broken (maybe try hosting your images somewhere online and referencing that link from the pen).

Anyways: one possible solution would be to put a 'restart' button inside of the form you display when all your winning criteria is met.

```
<div id="form_container">
  <h1>Congratulations! You found all 5!</h1>
  <p>Are you ready for the next Round?</p><br />
  //This is new
  <button id="restart">Yes<button>
</div>
```

You can set a listener on this button's click event in your javascript like so:

```
//Put this in the scope of your $(document).ready(function() { }); function
$('#restart').click(function() {
  $('#form_container').css('display', 'none');
  restart();
})
```

This will hide the form and call the restart function which would be defined to set all of the criteria back to the way it was.

```
var restart = function() {
  $('#camera-diff').data('clicked', false);
  $('#down-diff').data('clicked', false);
  $('#eye-diff').data('clicked', false);
  $('#flour-diff').data('clicked', false);
  $('#uni-diff').data('clicked', false);
  //You can also change the images here
  $('#camera-diff').css('background','url(contest_files/camera2.png) no-repeat top left;'
  //etc
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle for you to copy and try on your local with working references to your images: https://jsfiddle.net/L6h5cryn/